# Why does 'find' on the terminal tell me it found files that don't exist?

Tags: bash, find

I was poking around, looking for a file on the terminal (I'm using OS):

```
monica$ sudo find / -type f -name '*neo4j-desktop*'
```

Fine, right? So here's what I get back:

```
/Applications/Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.3.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/neo4j-desktop-3.1.3.jar
/Applications/Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.3.app/Contents/Resources/app/lib/neo4j-desktop-3.1.3.jar
find: /dev/fd/Applications: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/Applications: No such file or directory
```

This has popped up for me on occasion. Why does `find` want to tell me it **couldn't** find a file twice? This makes no rational sense.

Comment: What is `/dev/fd/Applications`? Why are you searching in the `/dev` (e.g. *device*) file system. Those files can be `nodes`, `UUID` references, `TTY`s, etc.. Your problem is you have not limited your search to valid files `find` likes.

Comment: I thought `/` would recursively search from the root...

Comment: It will, but you have `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` hanging off `/` that you probably want to avoid....

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  That is right and find didn't find the same files, look at the path. one is in `bin` and the other in `lib`. There is a good chance that one of those files is a symbolic link. In that case use the `-H` option so that `find` will not follow symbolic links

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck look at the `-mount` option to `find` (some implementations use the `-xdev` option for the same purpose) to skip mounted filesystems like `/dev`, `/proc`, and `/sys`...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the good advice. I need to get more savy with `find` I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `-path -prune` combination in this case

```
find -H / -type f -path "/dev*" -or -path "/proc*" -or -path "/sys*" -prune -o -name "*neo4j-desktop*" -print
```

Or do it like below

```
find -H  / -mount -type f -name "*neo4j-desktop*"
```

The [[ **find manpage** ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says :

> -mount
>   Don't descend directories on other filesystems. An alternate name for -xdev,
>   for compatibility with some other versions of find.